# Build error for a .Net Framework 4.8 application on Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: .net, compilation, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a .Net Framework 4.8 application with multiple projects in the solution. 
The main project(.csproj) - "Project A" has Platform target as 'x86' for both Debug and Release configurations, whereas other projects have 'Any CPU' as platform targets for both Debug and Release configurations.The solution builds (compiles) fine in Visual Studio, but when I am trying to create and run YAML build pipeline using the VSBuild@1 task, it's failing with errors. The errors are thrown by a test project which has 'project A' as a reference, the errors are thrown as if the "Project A" is not added as a reference. But the project A is added as reference to the test project.

By the way am new to YAML pipelines, but I believe the YAML pipeline is fine for .net app.

The errors thrown are all of type:
**Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MessageHandler' does not exist in the namespace 'xx.xx.xx.ProjectA' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**
 
"Build-Windows" is a windows self-hosted agent that's a Windows Server 2019 OS. I have tried a lot to resolve, but no luck. What am I missing? Any help would be very much appreciated!!
 
My YAML pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
- none
 
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
 
pool: Build-Windows
 
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: ⬇ NuGet - Install
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 
    checkLatest: true
 
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName:  NuGet - Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.Config
 
 
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName:  Build 
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
 
 
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
 
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: ⬆ Publish Artifacts
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: Package
    TargetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

I tried changing the target platforms and changed YAML build pipeline multiple times but no luck.

Comment: Does the test project have an `Any CPU` build configuration even though it's referencing an `x86` only project?

Comment: Yes, it has 'Any CPU' for both debug and release configurations. It's an old project probably there's some linkage issues.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your solution file? That would help identify the build configuration errors. It's highly likely that you are not building the x86 project when '`Any CPU`' is built meaning that the ProjectA dll will not even exist when the test project is trying to reference ProjectA types.

Comment: Do you mean to include the .sln file? May I know what do I need to look for? Ya I felt the same, but it's working fine in VS

Answer (score 0):

There could be any of a few problems going on. It's possible that the "clean" build machine environment leads to problems that you aren't seeing on your local box.

Check your build configuration:

[image: Image showing how to navigate to the configuration manager in Visual Studio 2022 by using the Build menu bar and selecting "Configuration Manager..."]

And see if the x86 is being built when the project is under `Any CPU` config.

[image: Visual Studio's Build Configuration Manager]

If it's not, then what's likely happening is that you built `x86` at some point and building the `Any CPU` platform is using the previously built version. What you'll need to do in the pipeline is make sure you build the `x86` version first, then build the `Any CPU` version.